# Disable the window on the background

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window that opens another window. I want that when this window it's opened i can't do anything on the parent window. (I'm not allowed to click buttons for example)
How I can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

You need to call the [`ShowDialog` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) instead of `Show` to show the second window as a modal dialog.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 11):

You want a modal window instead of a modeless window.  A modal window means that the parent window is not usable while the child window is open.

You can open a modal window with [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).

You can open a modeless window with just [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry I meant ShowDialog instead of ShowModal

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend you to use MDI scenario behaving as child and parent windows but for instance according to the point you can use code below.

```
NewWindow.ShowDialog() method instead of NewWindow.Show() as it will disable background window
```

but that's not good practice we should implement MDI.

I've never seen a desktop application opening on multiple windows and disabling older ones.